# I am getting run-time Error 1004 on first run

Tags: vba, excel

When I run the following code for the first time I get a run-time `Error 1004`.

```
Sheet2.Range("B112").Value = ("=Large($D$8:$D$73,1")
```

However if I open the Editor and re-run the code it works.

The code assigns the formula to the cell in another sheet to get the largest number in given range in that sheet itself. The code is triggered by a command button click present in different sheet.

Please help me or suggest alternate code to do this.

Comment: If you are using an `Activex Contol` , which I think you are, it will not work. Transfer your code in a module instead and use `Form Control` and assign your macro.

Comment: @PortlandRunner There is no need to use `Set` here. `Sheet2` is a valid reference if we are to assume that it is one of the sheets property name.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Formula` as follows:

```
Sheet2.Range("B112").Formula = "=Large($D$8:$D$73,1)"
```